# UL class seems doesn't work on my footer

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I've been coding a website for some friends and since yesterday my ul class doesn't work on my footer. This ul is for displaying social icons and more. When I was coding on my localhost everything was good but since I've put the website on the server it totally messed up :(

Here is the HTML of my footer and the CSS applied on it.

Hope you can help me !

```css
ul.social_icons, li.social {
    margin-top:-23px;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
    max-width:25%;
    list-style: none;
    float:left;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

ul { 
    padding:0; 
    margin:0 0 0 10px;
}

.footer-social li {
    float:left; 
    list-style:none; 
    margin-left:5px;
}
```

```html
<footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">

    <div class="site-info">

        <p>Copyright © Gaëtan POIDEVIN <span class="sep"> | </span> <a href="http://gaetanpoidevin.fr" target="_blank">Gaëtan POIDEVIN</a></p>
    </div><!-- .site-info -->

    <ul class="footer_social">
        <li class="social"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/Defilenimages/" target="_blank"><img class="img-responisve" src="http://defilenimages.fr/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/facebook-1.png"></a></li>
        <li class="social"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC8cwap7ZLC8T2ZXKJzB1M8A" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://defilenimages.fr/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/youtube-1.png"></a></li>
        <li class="social"><a href="mailto:de.fil.en.images@gmail.com"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://defilenimages.fr/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/gmail-1.png"></a></li> 
        <li class="social"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://defilenimages.fr/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/musiclibre004-1.png"></li>
    </ul>
</footer><!-- #colophon -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you are using `width:25%` in your `li` tag but when you use percentage you are saying to `li` that i want to be `25%` of your parent width but your `ul` doesn't have width so it doesn't work.

> When using percentage (%) for width, authors must be aware that the
>   percentage is based on the element's parent, or in other words, the
>   width of the containing block. If your parent is set at 480px  then the percentage is based on that value.

Here you have a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dpjoe0Lt/) for your problem
I have added a fixed width for your `ul`you can add anything you want even using `%` but remember what i said for `%` value. Also i added `width:100%` to your `img` so it won't go outside of your `li` .

Here is a [link](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/width/) for more about `%` width

Comment: Thank you very much, I totally forgot to check this line !

But do you know why my ul class doens't show in my firebug ? It's driving me crazy :(

Comment: /EDIT/ 
Nevermind, I'm just really tired and I haven't change my ul class on my footer.php.
Really thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Mark as correct please :D You should send any screenshot from your firebug. Have you tried in chrome if it shows ?